# Finder folder icon showing items count when empty

Tags: macos, finder, desktop

In OSX 10.9.1, I have a folder on the desktop which is empty in the Finder view, but the icon info says '8 items' – see screen grab:

[image: screen grab]

I have checked for invisible files via search>show invisible and with an FTP app which lists files including those beginning with a dot (which are usually hidden), but cannot see 8 files.

Is this a known bug with desktop icons? Is there a solution? It's infuriating when deleting folders and wanting to make absolutely sure not to lose files.

Comment: And what does Terminal.app say when you run: ls -axhl ~/Desktop/REF ?

Comment: Thanks, I have since deleted the folder but as soon as I see the issue again I will run that terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

You must have a Folder Action script that does that, but it is not working correctly.

Right Click on the Folder "Ref"

Scroll down in pop up to Services,

new pop shows up

Click on the Folder Action setup

again a new window will pop up showing the scripts

This is what they look on 10.9.2 without any modifications by me

[image: folder action scripts]

If you have any other script, just simply uncheck it or use Edit if you know what you doing.

Comment: Thanks, I checked my folder actions but they were the same as yours, no extra ones.

Comment: I see you Tagged that Folder, not that is that, but try removing the Tag.