# View number of items in a folder in Icon view

Tags: macos

In Downloads folder I see that the number of items present in a folder is displayed under the folder name in Icon view.

But I am unable to view such detail in Desktop, Documents, etc folders. How can I get that info to be always displayed in the Icon view?

I checked Folder actions but I do not find any difference ([Finder folder icon showing items count when empty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124656/finder-folder-icon-showing-items-count-when-empty))

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option is called "Show item Info" and is toggled from the View menu rather from Preferences.

1. Select the finder window you want to apply this view to, even the desktop. And set it to icon view.
2. Go to the View menu and select "Show view options."
3. A window opens up (like below) check the Show Item Info checkbox.

Now folder icons will show the number of files in them for that window.

[image: Desktop > View Options]